# Anchor Tag Not working in Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint, eventreceiver

I have created an event receiver to trigger an e-mail whenever an item was added.in this event receiver email gets deliverd to the employee. In the e-mail content i would like to give a link so that the employee can go to the web site directly. but in my code i am facing some problem . here is my code

```
public string MailMsgBody_WU(string MailTo, SPItemEventProperties IERProperties)
   {
       string MMsgBody = "";

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Travel Request-MailMsgBody(): Begin");
       try
       {

           MMsgBody += "<table>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td>Hi,</td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><br></br></td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td> New Calendar Item Event" + IERProperties.ListTitle + " has been added into learning portal.</td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><br></br></td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td>Please click on the following link to view the details.</td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><br></br></td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><a href=" + http://tri02sharepoint:47709/Lists/Learning%20Calendar/calendar.aspx    + ">Click Here</a></td></tr>";           
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><br></br></td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td><br></br></td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td>Thanks,</td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "<tr><td>Learning Team</td></tr>";
           MMsgBody += "</table>";

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Travel Request-MailMsgBody(): End" + ex.Message.ToString());
       }
       return MMsgBody;
   }
```

i am getting the error in
`MMsgBody += "<tr><td><a href=" + http://tri02sharepoint:47709/Lists/Learning%20Calendar/calendar.aspx    + ">Click Here</a></td></tr>";`

http:// <---- here is the Error

These are the errors

> Error 1   Invalid expression term ':'
>   Error 2   ; expected
>   Error 3   ; expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
MMsgBody += "<tr><td><a href=" + http://tri02sharepoint:47709/Lists/Learning%20Calendar/calendar.aspx    + ">Click Here</a></td></tr>";
```

You are basically trying to call a function/field/member called "http://tri02sharepoint..." within your C# code, which obviously does not exist.

You should do this instead:

```
MMsgBody += "<tr><td><a href=\"http://tri02sharepoint:47709/Lists/Learning%20Calendar/calendar.aspx\">Click Here</a></td></tr>";
```

You need to escape special characters like <kbd>"</kbd> and you do that with a <kbd>\</kbd>.